# Is it OK to replace the preposition “through” with “during”?

Tags: prepositions, word-usage

> You'll hear the determination in the voice of a young field organizer who's working his way through college.

This is a line from President Obama's address. My question is why it is *through* college, not *during* college? Sometimes these prepositions confuse me.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. You may find that your questions are better suited to [ell.SE]; I invite you to visit both, and post where you find answers of the sort you need.

Comment: General reference: [work one's way through](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/work)

Comment: As a general rule, ***no*** preposition may be substituted for any other preposition in **all** of its uses and idioms. However, it is common for prepositions to be substitutable in **some** of their uses and idioms. _Through_, for instance, also means _finished_, but this is certainly not a meaning of _during_.

Answer (score 5):

‘Working your way through’ something means doing what is necessary in order to complete it. One ‘works one’s way through’ a problem or a challenge or difficult times.

The President isn't talking just about those who work *during* college; he is talking about those who must work in order to get *through* college.

Answer (score 0):

Through college' is fine because 'college' is often used as a phase in life (in terms of time). So just like we would say things like, "moving through time", we can say "moving through college".
Also, one works his way 'through' something(path), so we will have to re-structure the whole sentence if we want to use 'during college'. Eg: "You'll hear the determination in the voice of a young field organizer who works during his college days"
The later sounds less natural, btw.